# In unity, after LoadScene, is there common way to wait all monobehaviour#start to finish

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

following is my unitytest code:

```
        LoadScene("Scene/Level-2");
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => { return GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Arrow>(); });
        var arrow = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Arrow>();
```

I load a scene and WaitUntil some object is loaded

I hope find a way to omit `yield return new WaitUntil`, so is there way to  wait all MonoBehaviour#Start finish and then run code?

Comment: Your current code doesn't make sense. Hard to help you without knowing what you're loading or waiting to load. What exactly are you waiting to load? Maybe show what `LoadScene` is doing? Showing what you're loading is important to get a proper answer.

Comment: You typically want to wait until the entire scene is loaded since you don't know what additional dependencies Unity has injected. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36272697/when-does-the-loadscene-function-in-unity-change-the-scene

Answer (score 8):

The `Awake()` and `Start()` method is called on the first frame after an element is instantiated. So, if you load a scene and wait for the next frame, all the starts methods will be called.

This should work for you.

```
private IEnumerator LoadScene()
{
    // Start loading the scene
    AsyncOperation asyncLoadLevel = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("myLevel", LoadSceneMode.Single);
    // Wait until the level finish loading
    while (!asyncLoadLevel.isDone)
        yield return null;
    // Wait a frame so every Awake and Start method is called
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
}
```

Comment: Awake and Start runs on first frame but it didn't mean that their execution necessarily complete before the next frame.

Comment: Awake and Start are synchronous, that means that the frame won't continue until their execution is complete [Execution Order of Event Functions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html). The only way that a Start method isn't "complete" is if it calls a Coroutine.

Comment: You mean if there is no corroutine in start or Awake, then these methods will complete before the next frame at any cost.